# MUI Autocomplete pass input value as an object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am working on the autocomplete functionality and want to work with the multiple tags selected by the users. My question is how I can achieve this considering each tag is an object of the type

```
 type Keyword = {
    label: string;
    otherval: string;
  };
```

As some attributes for autocomplete I use multiple and freeSolo

```
 <Autocomplete
            multiple
            freeSolo
            id='tags-filled'
            options={keywords}
```

My biggest problem lies in figuring out whether it's possible to parse the user input when he presses enter as an object rather than a string. If I click however to create a new option the object gets created. So at the end I have at

```
onChange={(event, tagsList) => {
              /* setTags(tagsList); */
}}
```

the `tagsList` is a list of `Keyword || string` type. I would like to have `tagsList` being consistently consisting of `Keyword` elements.
The full code so far looks like this
`
<Autocomplete
multiple
freeSolo
id='tags-filled'
options={keywords}

```
          style={{ width: 600 }}
        
          onChange={(event, tagsList) => {
            const stringList = tagsList.map((item) => {
              if (typeof item === 'string') {
                return item;
              }
              return item.label;
            });
            console.log(stringList);
         
          }}
          sx={
      
            { color: BLACK, background: BLUE }
          }
          getOptionLabel={(option) => {
            // Value selected with enter, right from the input
            if (typeof option === 'string') {
              return option;
            }
            // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
            /*  if (option.inputValue) {
            return option.inputValue;
          } */
            // Regular option
            return option.label;
          }}
          filterOptions={(options, params) => {
            const filtered = filter(options, params);
            // Input value passed as a string argument
            const { inputValue } = params;
            // Suggest the creation of a new value
            const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option.label);
            if (inputValue !== '' && !isExisting) {
              filtered.push({
                label: inputValue,
                topProductPrompt: `"${inputValue}"`,
              });
            } else {
              filtered.push({
                label: inputValue,
                topProductPrompt: `"${inputValue}"`,
              });
            }

            return filtered;
          }}
          renderOption={(props, option) => (
            <span {...props} style={{ color: BLACK, backgroundColor: WHITE }}>
              {option.label}
            </span>
          )}
          renderTags={(tagValues: readonly any[], getTagProps) =>
            tagValues.map((option: any, index: number) => (
              <Chip
                sx={{ color: WHITE, background: BLUE, bgcolor: ROSA }}
                variant='outlined'
                // By pressing enter string is parsed, otherwise the whole object
                label={typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.label}
                {...getTagProps({ index })}
              />
            ))
          }
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              sx={{ color: WHITE, background: BLUE }}
              variant='filled'
              label=''
              style={{ flex: 1, margin: '0 50px 0 0', color: 'white' }}
              inputProps={{
                style: { color: 'white' },
                ...params.inputProps,
              }}
              placeholder='Product keywords'
            />
          )}
        />`
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is possible (however, your object shape might have to change). Is the initial list of keywords empty, passed to your custom component via props, or available to the custom component via access to state that is managed external to your component?

Comment: The initial list looks like this `const keywords: readonly Keyword[] = [
    { label: 'Testlabel', otherval: testval' },...,
  ];`. It's declared outside the autocomplete in the general scope. I would think that autocomplete would take the initial list as an indicator on how to evaluate, the input values, as an object or a string, but it doesn't

Comment: Could you please clarify the part of your question that says, *user input when he presses enter as an object rather than a string*? How would it be possible for a user to key in an object? It sounds like there may have been confusion about the Autocomplete `options` property and `value` property. After looking at my answer let me know if you have further questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

> I would like to have tagsList being consistently consisting of Keyword elements.

To address this request directly: This can be done. The [MUI API docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props) declare the `tagsList` data type as **`value: T | Array<T>`**. This suggests that if your Autocomplete `value` property is configured to be an array of **`<T>`**, then Autocomplete should send **`<T>`** or **`Array<T>`** to the `tagsList` argument in the onChange callback. Your code is missing the `value` property. You could update your component accordingly to make it work.

---

As for validation, the functions below can validate the input. You can see these functions in action in this [demo](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-75971935). Source code for the demo is available on [SourceHut](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekofeigen/autocomplete-validation). The demo uses an additional property (`isValid`) that might require augmenting your Typescript **Keyword** interface. The demo is in JavaScript, not Typescript.

### Autocomplete properties

Some important Autocomplete properties to understand are these:

##### options

```
options={ keywords.map( ( keyword ) => keyword.label ) }
```

- Generate the strings to be rendered in the select drop-down list.

##### value

```
value={ keywords.map( ( keyword ) => keyword.label ) }
```

- The callback for the `value` property assumes that the **Keyword** *label* property can be used as a unique identifier for a keyword. If *label* is not unique the Keyword interface needs to be augmented with an *id* property, and *id* should be used instead of *label*. Such an update would also require an update to the callback in `isOptionEqualToValue`

##### onChange

```
onChange={ validateInput }
```

- Send the selected or user-entered value to a callback for validation.

##### filterSelectedOptions

```
filterSelectedOptions={ true }
```

- Omit selected options from the drop-down list. (Optional).

##### isOptionEqualToValue

```
isOptionEqualToValue={ ( option, label ) => option == label }
```

- Comparator function used to determine if the value in the text field represents one of the **Keyword** objects. Include if array elements in `options` need to be converted or coerced to different data types to be compared to values in `value`.

### Validation

The functions below perform the validation. `keywords` is assumed to be in scope for the `validateValue` and `validateInput` functions.

```
/**
 * Check for duplication in the keyword list or the list of user-entered keyword values.
 * This function can be modified based on validation requirements
 * (e.g. exclude curse words). :-)
 *
 * @param {string} label - Most recently entered value by the user. 
 * @param {Object[]} validatedItems - Keyword objects containing recently
 *  entered values that have already been validated.
 *
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function validateValue( label, validatedItems ) {
    let isValid = true;
    const selectedValues = keywords.map( ( item ) => item.label );
    const validatedValues = validatedItems.map( ( item ) => item.label );
    const combinedValues = selectedValues.concat( validatedValues );
    // const combinedValues = combinedValues.concat( curseWords ); :-)
    let validationCollator = new Intl.Collator(
        'en',
        {
            usage: 'search',
            numeric: false,
            sensitivity: 'base'
        }
    );
    const matches = combinedValues.filter(
        ( value ) => validationCollator.compare( value, label ) === 0
    );

    if ( matches.length > 0 ) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}


/**
 * Main validation function.
 *
 * @param {Object} event - Synthetic React event object.
 * @param {string[]} inputs - Strings from text input field.
 * @param {string} reason - MUI reason why the onChange event was triggered.
 */
function validateInput( event, inputs, reason ) {
    let newKeywordList = [];

    if ( 'createOption' == reason || 'selectOption' == reason ) {
        let validatedItems = [];

        let value = inputs[ inputs.length - 1 ];
        if ( /[^À-ÿ0-9a-zA-Z_. -]/.test( value ) || value.length == 0 ) {
            // Use your own validation here. This just checks that entered characters are
            // within certain character code ranges (by returning true if a character is
            // not within the accepted ranges). You can add code here to display user
            // feedback if there is user error. Currently, invalid characters
            // (e.g. punctuation marks))just silently fail without feedback.
        } else {
            // Decide what you want to do with invalid entries.
            // Currently, invalid entries are retained with isValid set to false.
            let isValid = validateValue( value, validatedItems );
            validatedItems.push( {
                label: value,
                otherVal: '', // Enter whatever goes here.
                isValid
            } );
        }

        newKeywordList = [].concat( keywords, validatedItems );
    } else if ( 'removeOption' == reason ) {
        newKeywordList = inputs.map( ( id ) => listById[ id ] );
    } else if ( 'clear' == reason ) {
        // Noop.
    }

    setKeywordList( newKeywordList );

    // Optional. Call callback function to update parent component for user
    // feedback. E.g. update a list page.
    // callback( newKeywordList ); 
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for throughout answer. First I have a question. So you managed to process the input as object through `onChange={ validateInput }`? I've tried as well to alter the input values with `onInputChange={(event, value, reason) => { ...  }} ` or in `onChange`  but I couldn't change the `value`, because I received the (typescript specific) error messages that I can't assign `Keyword` object to a string. So I don't know if your solution works for Typescript. I have a shorter hacky solution `onChange={(event, tagsList) => {const stringList = tagsList.map((item) => { return ...}}`

Comment: @Rareform Your question: *So you managed to process the input as object...?* Answer: No. Inputs are not objects. Inputs are strings. When a user types text into the text field, they are typing strings. MUI Autocomplete manages the text input as an array of strings (when the user clicks Enter, that terminates the entry of one string). In my sample code the Autocomplete properties `options` and `value` are of the data type **string[]** (not *Keyword* or *Keyword[]*). Can you please post the full code for your component? I might be able to see where the problem is if I can see the code. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the original text. I can get what I want with stringList. However I was curious, whether there exists a standard approach, so that the text input is managed as objects instead of an array of strings. If I click on the mouse to select the option the input is namely parsed as an object. It's probably because I am clicking on existing options , which are objects instead of when I am entering a string and press enter. But yeah, the answer seems it's not an integrated feature to consider entered strings as objects of the same format as options.

Comment: @Rareform The **validateInput** function has the statement `let value = inputs[ inputs.length - 1 ];`. This tells you that the `inputs` argument is processed as an array (of strings). That statement extracts the most recently entered string (the last array element). And, that string is used to craate a **Keyword** object. That object is appended to the `validatedItems` array by calling `validatedItems.push()`. `validatedItems` is appended to `newKeywordList` which is assigned to the `keywords` variable. `validatedItems`,  `newKeywordList`, and `keywords` all have the data type **Keyword[]**.

Comment: @Rareform You say: *If I click on the mouse to select the option the input is namely parsed as an object.* This could be where the misconception is. As I've mentioned in an earlier comment the MUI Autocomplete `options` property is an array of strings (not an array of objects). So, when a user clicks an option from the select drop-down, MUI Autocomplete is submitting a string into the text field, and not an object.

Comment: @Rareform You ask: *whether there exists a standard approach...?* Answer: No. Since data entry is managed via an input text form field, fundamentally we are managing text input. Native HTML input text elements manage content via their `value` fields (which can only store text). Since we are using React and the MUI library, we're hijacking the native HTML element `value` field and managing the content independently (e.g. via a **keywords** object array). This is what is referred to as using a **controlled** component. We are controlling the data management, not the native HTML element.

Comment: @Rareform Thanks for posting your code. The code does not reveal the data type of the `keywords` variable. But, we can see in your **onChange** callback that your `tagsList` variable should act like my `inputs` variable. MUI Autocomplete passes `tagsList` as an array of strings. So, there is no need for type checking with `typeof`. And, `label` is not a property of `item`. Likewise, the **getOptionLabel** callback doesn't need type checking. The definition of the **getOptionLabel** callback depends on how you've defined the callback for the Autocomplete `options` property.

Comment: @Rareform So, to circle back to your original request, *I would like to have tagsList being consistently consisting of Keyword elements.*: This could be possible. The [MUI API docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props) declare the `tagsList` data type as **value: T | Array<T>**. This suggests that if your Autocomplete `value` property is configured to be an array of <T>, then Autocomplete should send <T> or Array<T> to the `tagsList` argument in the onChange callback. Your code is missing the `value` property. You could update your component accordingly to see if it works.

Comment: @Rareform Just clarify: To use **Keyword** objects exclusively might require avoiding **freeSolo**. **freeSolo** allows users to enter arbitrary text into the text input field. This means Autocomplete will send the **string** data type to `tagsList`. And, since the tagsList data type is **<T> | Array<T>**, the **<T>** must be consistent. So, if strings are sent, then only *<string>* or an *Array of <strings>* can be sent. Sorry for all the messages. But, I thought this one would be important to save your time.

Comment: Indeed your suggestion with setting value to a list of `<T>` seems to work. I suggest you editing the answer, so that it's not mentioned only in a comment and then I will accept it. I haven't understood how `value`  works previously, I thought it needs `<T>`, not a list of `<T>`

Comment: Thanks @Rareform. I updated the answer. If you'd like me to remove the extended list of my comments here, just let me know.